# The Bundle ID you entered has already been used for a LITE version

Tags: iphone, bundle

I'm trying to add a Lite version for one of my iPhone apps.
In iTunes Connect, I click "Add New App".
Then, on the first screen appearing, I need to enter App Name, SKU Number and Bundle ID. The problem is I get the error "The Bundle ID you entered has already been used." although it is NOT used in any other application submitted.

Anybody else encountered it?
P.S. It seems the Bundle ID combobox does not show ALL of the App IDs I have... how is it populated?

Comment: Sent a mail to iTunes Connect support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after a couple of mails to Apple and a few days, the updated list of Bundle IDs magically appeared in the desired combobox.
I guess I'll have to live with the fact that it's a kind of magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and logging in again at iTunes Connect fixed this problem for me - the new bundle id showed up afterwards. About 5 minutes had passed also, you might want to try waiting a bit if logging out and in does not help.